# Rails-friendly DHTML grid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, components, dhtml

I have an Excel-based UI that I'd like to replicate as closely as possible in a Rails view. I'm looking for a DHTML grid control that ...

1. can be easily formatted (w.r.t. column width, font size, etc.)
2. is responsive (the page will have up to 200 columns and 200 rows)
3. can have cells containing select controls
4. has good Rails integration (ideally, is available as a Rails plug-in with an idiomatic API)
5. supports at least FF, IE, & Safari (potentially targeting iPhones ...)

Can anyone recommend (either for or against) a DHTML grid they've used in the past?

I'm happy to look at both commercial and free solutions.  If you or your company sells such a thing, this is an excellent opportunity to plug it :-)

Comment: I haven't found one I liked. I integrated Flexigrid quite deeply into my app before pulling it out because I wasn't happy with the user-experience.

Comment: Thanks - that's what I'm hoping to avoid.  The app is quite simple, with the exception of this one view.  I *could* build it myself manually, but I think that'd at least double the development time of the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look at: [Gridify - A Ruby wrapper and Rails plugin for jqGrid](http://www.vaporbase.com/postings/Gridify_-_A_Ruby_wrapper_and_Rails_plugin_for_jqGrid)

Comment: Thanks - this definitely seems to be what I was looking for.  I think I may still end up rolling my own but Gridify looks pretty promising.

Comment: Just for people who come her now (as I did): the project is no longer maintained: https://github.com/linoj/gridify.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say active scaffold is the mother of grids on rails.
(Rails 3 fork) https://github.com/vhochstein/active_scaffold

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think GRIDIFY is an excellent solution, the interface is very nice. This plug in can give you a lot of features, you can even sort all the data. I am just beginning with ruby and I can not customize it very well but I think there are many things you can take advantage of.